# How to associated a class to a control on XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, controls

I am looking at a source code presented on Microsoft website where a class is derived from the `Adorner` class and using override a new style been added to a `TextBox` in XAML. The code is not complete so I'm having problem on how to assign this code to the control (`TextBox`) on XAML.

Can an expert give me some ideas how to associated the `TextBox` with the inherited class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx#Y1457

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would claim that MSDN is clear enough:

> To bind an adorner to a particular UIElement, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Call the static method GetAdornerLayer to get an AdornerLayer object for the UIElement to be adorned. GetAdornerLayer walks up the visual tree, starting at the specified UIElement, and returns the first adorner layer it finds. (If no adorner layers are found, the method returns null.)
> 2. Call the Add method to bind the adorner to the target UIElement.

You may not be able to do this in XAML unless you can get the methods invoked by the parser, e.g. via the `IList` interface. Of course you can expand XAML almost arbitrarily with [markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) that do the necessary imperative steps for you.

Comment: That is right! no idea how I missed that part of page...  thank you.

Comment: Hi HB, yes, I did but it says I'm require of having a reputation of 15. Let me know what I should do.

Comment: @amitkohan: Only upvoting (up-arrow) requires 15 reputation, accepting (check-mark) can always be done.